# softkeyboard not working when barcode scanner is connected to tablet

Tags: android

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

Using this code also soft keyboard is not appearing when barcode scanner is connected please help with this

Comment: I have same problem. But not able found any answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8143805/how-to-disable-physical-keyboard-in-codeuse-virtual-keyboard-all-the-time

Comment: What kind of barcode scanner you're using?

Comment: i am using SC-8070S barcode scanner and HCL U1 tablet

Answer (score 2):

I found solution and it worked for Nexus 4.4.2

```
if(getResources().getConfiguration().hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO){
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showInputMethodPicker();
    }
```

You have to disable hardware keyboard on the popup message.

Answer (score 0):

Android can only have **one** keyboard connected at a time.

The scanner counts as a keyboard.